# SQLite code to convert date ( dd/mm/yyyy to yyyyQ1) not working in BigQuery SQL editor

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In order to visualize a bubble chart in Gapminder, all dates have to be converted from, dd/mm/yyyy to yyyyQ1. This code does the conversion on in SQLite.

I am able to convert the dates, using this code, on my local SQLite client, then load the outputted csv file into Gapminder to view the bubble chart.

However this 25 gb database has outgrown the SQLite client and needs to be queried using BigQuery.

There are two problems.

1: First, for BigQuery, this code needs to convert the csv date column from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy.

Then for Gapminder it needs the final output to be yyyyQ1..

The problem is when I run the same code in the BigQuery web UI SQL editor, I receive an error, "unexpected pipe":

Input:

```
replace(substr(PCR.repdte,6),'/','')||'q'||CAST(1+ . 
      ((substr(PCR.repdte,1,2)-1) / 3) AS INTEGER)
```

Output:

```
  Syntax error: Unexpected "|" at [3:44]
```

[image]

Here is the entire statement I successfully run on the SQLite client, and attempted to run on the Bigquery SQL web ui editor:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT
      replace(substr(PCR.repdte,6),'/','')||'q'||CAST(1+ . 
      ((substr(PCR.repdte,1,2)-1) / 3) AS INTEGER) 
  FROM All_Reports_19920331_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as PCR) AS 
    Quarter,
  (SELECT 
      Round(AVG(PCR.lnlsdepr))
      FROM All_Reports_19920331_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as PCR) AS 
      NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
 (SELECT sum(CAST(LD.IDdepsam as int))
 FROM 
  'All_Reports_19920331_Deposits_Based_on_the_Dollars250,000_
  Reporting_Threshold' AS LD) AS DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  (SELECT
     replace(substr(PCR.repdte,6),'/','')||'q'||CAST(1+ . 
    ((substr(PCR.repdte,1,2)-1) / 3) AS INTEGER) --converts date format 
    from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyyq1 (financial quarters)
  FROM All_Reports_19920630_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as PCR) AS 
  Quarter,
  (SELECT 
      Round(AVG(PCR.lnlsdepr))
  FROM All_Reports_19920630_Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as PCR) AS 
      NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
  (SELECT sum(CAST(LD.IDdepsam as int))
  FROM 
    'All_Reports_19920630_Deposits_Based_on_the_Dollars
     250,000_Reporting_Threshold' AS LD) AS 
     DepositAccountsWith$LessThan$250k
```

The goal is to convert the date from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy so BigQuery can read it. Then convert it again to, yyyyQ1, so Gapminder can read it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all dates have to be converted from, dd/mm/yyyy to yyyyQ1

Below simplified example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '31/12/2018' dt UNION ALL
  SELECT '31/01/2019'
)
SELECT dt, 
  CONCAT(
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y', PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt)),
    'Q', CAST(EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt)) AS STRING)
  ) date_yyyyQ1
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row dt          date_yyyyQ1  
1   31/12/2018  2018Q4   
2   31/01/2019  2019Q1
```